# dotnet CLI “error: There are no versions available for the package 'myCustomPackage'.”

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget-package, nuget-server, asp.net-core-cli

I've added my private source of packages that hosted on gitlab by this command

`dotnet nuget add source`

its done successfully and added to my list of sources, then I've pushed my packages on it, the packages are also up when I check them on `gitlab repo/packages & registeries`.
Now the problem is when I want to add this packages on other projects:

`dotnet add package <myPackageName> -s <mySourceNameThatHasAlreadyAdded>`

[image]

dotnet Cli says `There are no versions available for the package <myPackageName>` however already two versions of this package available on gitlab(mySourceNameThatHasAlreadyAdded).

how colud I solve this issue?

Comment: Are your packages prerelease-packages? Have you checked of these packages are compatible with the projects you are trying to add them to?

Comment: yes, my packages are in release mode and about compatibility, of course these packages are built in .net standard 2.1 and I just wanna use them in .net core 5 projects.
@D.J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I don't know why but the issue was resolved by eliminating  the

`-s <mySourceNameThatHasAlreadyAdded>`

from the add command and just write

`dotnet add package <myPackageName>`

and because my private source package is the only package source in the result of

`dotnet nuget list source`

command, without any idea now it works!